# Increase resolution of java screenshot

Tags: java, screenshot

I am using the following code to take a screenshot in Java:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException{
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Path/To/screenshot.png"));
    }
}
```

This code works, but the screen shot outputted is fairly low resolution. **How can I increase the resolution of the screenshot?**

Comment: I am not going to down-vote. But, this question _might_ get downvotes because you've not tried anything at all. You should've atleast Googled for your problem once.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I have googled this problem. I always google my problem before asking on Stack Overflow. The reason I came to SO this time was because I was unsuccessful in finding anything useful.

Comment: Have you compared the resulting image size with the screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code. I have a screen resolution of 1680x1050 pixels, and the generated png file has exactly this size.

Comment: Well, my mac's screen looks a lot better than the screen shot I took of it with the code above.

Comment: You probably need to zoom in in your image viewer software. Did you check the pixel size of the image?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need this before new Robot

```java
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1");
```

When you set desktop system scale,the java ui also scale.
[Desktop scale set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/terJL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use Robot.createMultiResolutionScreenCapture, this was [added in Java 9+](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214233).

For example (using Kotlin):

```
    val graphicsDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().defaultScreenDevice
    val screenWidth = graphicsDevice.displayMode.width
    val screenHeight = graphicsDevice.displayMode.height

    val robot = Robot(graphicsDevice)
    val rect = Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().screenSize)

    val multiResolutionScreenshot = robot.createMultiResolutionScreenCapture(rect)
    val screenshot = multiResolutionScreenshot.getResolutionVariant(
            screenWidth.toDouble(), screenHeight.toDouble())

    ImageIO.write(screenshot as BufferedImage, "png", File("Path/To/screenshot.png"))
```